# SFML and Box2D SetUserData can't convert argument from const char [4] to void *

Tags: c++, box2d, sfml

I am coding a platformer in sfml and box2d, I want to code some boxes I can push around, but for some reason `body->SetUserData("box")` says that it cannot `convert const char [4] to void *`. I am following a tutorial. In the tutorial everything works fine, but for me this error appears:

`Error    C2664   'void b2Body::SetUserData(void *)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'const char [4]' to 'void *'`

Tutorial: (It is in Russian)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-eJXg2tGcyM

Code for the box:

```
b2PolygonShape shape;
shape.SetAsBox(30 / SCALE, 30 / SCALE);

b2BodyDef bdef;
bdef.type = b2_dynamicBody;

bdef.position.Set(600 / SCALE, 100 / SCALE);
b2Body *body = World.CreateBody(&bdef);
body->CreateFixture(&shape, 2);
body->SetUserData("box");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That tutorial probably relied on non-conformant behavior in VS that allowed conversion of string literals to non-const-qualified pointer to `char`. So you should either modify your code to be const-correct (recommended) or enable that old behavior by using [`/Zc:strictStrings-` compilation option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/zc-strictstrings-disable-string-literal-type-conversion?view=vs-2019) (not recommended).

Comment: Also, is doing ```const char* box[] = {"box"}``` doing it correctly? It seems to fix everything, but is there a better way of doing it? (not using /Zc:stringStrings- even though that also fixed the problem)

Comment: @Kerrot `const char* box[] = {"box"}` is correct, but how is this related to `SetUserData`? Anyway, if you are using this string to "tag" box2d body then it would probably be ok to just cast `body->SetUserData(const_cast<char *>("box")); ` and then cast back to correct type `static_cast<char const *>(body->GetUserData())` when retrieving it.

Comment: Ok, thank you. const char* box[] = {"box}" is related, because I used it in the SetUserData.

Comment: @Kerrot If `const char* box[] = {"box"}` was a stack-allocated then stored user data pointer would become invalid once box went out of scope.